# Chrome profile initial setup: install enterprise controlled extension BEFORE first run

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I have a unique use case. At work, I've recently been made owner over an internal corporate app. Our app launches a Chrome instance in app-mode (i.e. the flag `--app=<internalURL>`). Additionally, we install a Chrome extension with Chrome's enterprise management `ExtensionsInstallForcelist`. The extension comes from the Chrome web store. This setup works great for us in most cases; the extension runs in our app.

However, there is one unique scenario where the extension isn't loading. In one configuration, we create a temporary, one-time-use Chrome user directory and launch Chrome with `--user-data-dir=<newdir>`. So, when Chrome launches, the directory is empty and Chrome creates a new Default profile in this new user data directory. As expected, the extension is installed during this launch. However, it seems the extension service worker does not start at first launch - problematic when the profile is one-time-use.

Is there a way to fully install and start an extension in a fresh Chrome profile before Chrome launches (or while Chrome launches but before Chrome loads our web app in `--app=<internalURL>`)?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Try using an MV2 extension with a persistent background script. Another thing to try is to add "background" to "permissions" in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm the extension we're using is MV3, but I could maybe test an MV2. I haven't tried "permissions": ["background"]. I'll have to try that out. How do think it will play with a fresh Chrome profile?